# using flask in a class and threading process

Tags: python, class, flask, python-multithreading

I use flask to create a web application on a private network.

The aim is to get information from the user and get a file uploaded by the user to save it.
They are differents users on this private network and my issue is to process data from different user when they are connected at the same time ( so they send information and file at the same time ).

My idea is to use python class to open a new instance when a user use the application ( so all the user information will be stock in a private instance ) and use the threading module to improve the speed of my programm ( they will be a thread where the application will be executed and a thread where the uploaded file will be saved )

I discovered python class the last week so please explain all your words ^^

Answer (score 0):

[`flask.Flask.run`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run) accepts additional keyword arguments (`**options`) that it forwards to [`werkzeug.serving.run_simple`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple) - one of those arguments is `threaded` which defauls to `True` as of Flask 1.0 and this runs the server in multi-threaded mode.

So for the latest versions of Flask, the default development server will be able to serve multiple clients simultaneously by default, and will handle that for you on its own. For older versions of Flask, you can explicitly pass `threaded=True` to enable this behaviour.

If you're running an older Flask version all you have to do is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you ! I will try that and keep you inform